# How to run a batch file having plink.exe using php

Tags: php, bash, plink

Below is my code

1. deploy.php

   ```
   <?php

     exec("deploy.bat", $d, $e);
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($d);
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($e); exit;

   ?>
   ```
2. deploy.txt

   ```
   eval `ssh-agent`

   ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucketkey

   cd /usr/share/nginx/www_old/repos.git

   echo "calling git pull"

   git pull

   echo "git pull successful now moving files"
   ```
3. deploy.bat

   ```
   plink.exe -ssh -i abcd.ppk -m deploy.txt ubuntu@abcd.in
   ```

When I run deploy.php it returns me following output:

```
Array
(
)
0
```

This batch files works properly when I directly run it.

PS: All the files are in the same directory. PHP is not in safe mode. exec is not a disabled function inside php.ini. Am using LAMP on windows 8.

Comment: Your problem might be related to permissions. Make sure that the Apache user (most likely will be `www-data`) has permissions to execute `plink.exe` and `cmd.exe`.

Comment: How to give permission for the same?

Comment: Use the `CACLS` command and give permissions for `plink.exe`, `cmd.exe` and `php.exe`. The command is `CACLS c:\programs\php\php.exe /E /G «username»:F` (you should adjust the filepath)